# Filter dataframe based on another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, pipeline

I have a sample dataframe df

| City | Flow |
| --- | --- |
| Berlin | True |
| Berlin | False |
| Berlin | False |
| Munich | True |
| Munich | False |
| Frankfurt | True |
| Frankfurt | False |
| Amsterdam | True |
| Amsterdam | False |

I want to filter dataframe df1 where Flow column is True for all cities except Frankfurt and Amsterdam such that df becomes

| City | Flow |
| --- | --- |
| Berlin | True |
| Munich | True |
| Frankfurt | True |
| Frankfurt | False |
| Amsterdam | True |
| Amsterdam | False |

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional selection:

```py
df[ (df.Flow==True) | (df.City.isin(['Frankfurt', 'Amsterdam']))]
```

Output:

```
        City   Flow
0     Berlin   True
3     Munich   True
5  Frankfurt   True
6  Frankfurt  False
7  Amsterdam   True
8  Amsterdam  False
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) chained by boolean mask in column `Flow` by `|` for bitwise `OR` and filter in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df['Flow'] | df['City'].isin(['Frankfurt', 'Amsterdam'])]
print (df)
        City   Flow
0     Berlin   True
3     Munich   True
5  Frankfurt   True
6  Frankfurt  False
7  Amsterdam   True
8  Amsterdam  False
```